# Podman-compose versus podman run regarding environment variables

Tags: podman, podman-compose

I would like some input on `podman-compose` and `podman` (I tried with `docker` and `docker-compose` with the same result) regarding environment variables, please consider the following scenario:

I've a binary file `my-binary` in `/tmp/my-binaries`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello World"
```

I've created a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"                                                                                                  
                                                                                                              
services:                                                                                                     
  test-container:                                                                                             
    image: python:3.9-slim                                                                                    
    environment:                                                                                              
      - PATH="/home/minkiu/.local/bin:/home/minkiu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/minkiu/.pyenv/bin:/tmp/my_binaries"
    volumes:                                                                                                  
      - "/tmp/my_binaries:/tmp/my_binaries"                                                                   
    command: ["my-binary"]
```

where I am trying to append to `PATH` the directory where I have my binaries and map it with the `volumes` key.

Now my expectation is that upon `podman-compose up` this I should see `Hello World`, but that's not the case, I get:

```
Error: unable to start container <container-id>: executable file `my-binary` not found in $PATH: No such file or directory: OCI runtime attempted to invoke a command that was not found
125
```

By default `podman-compose`'s output is quite verbose, so I can see the command:

```
podman create --name=podman-test_test-container_1 --pod=podman-test --label io.podman.compose.config-hash=123 --label io.podman.compose.project=podman-test --label io.podman.compose.version=0.0.1 --label com.docker.compose.container-number=1 --label com.docker.compose.service=test-container -e PATH="/home/minkiu/.local/bin:/home/minkiu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/minkiu/.pyenv/bin:/tmp/my_binaries" -v /tmp/my_binaries:/tmp/my_binaries --add-host test-container:127.0.0.1 --add-host podman-test_test-container_1:127.0.0.1 python:3.9-slim my-binary
```

So I grab the same command, and perform a `podman run`:

```
podman run --rm -e PATH="/home/minkiu/.local/bin:/home/minkiu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/minkiu/.pyenv/bin:/tmp/my_binaries" -v /tmp/my_binaries:/tmp/my_binaries python:3.9-slim my-binary
```

And I get the expected output.

Some research made me aware that `run` is `create, start and attach` all in one.

So my question is, why is not working through the `podman-compose` and it is through `podman run` ?

Is `podman run` really something **more** than just `podman {create,start,attach}` ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue you described which in my environment is related to the SELinux configuration. So I solved the problem with an estra `:Z` in `volumes`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  test-container:
    image: python:3.9-slim
    environment:
      - PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/tmp/my_binaries"
    volumes:
      - /tmp/my_binaries:/tmp/my_binaries:Z
    command: ["/tmp/my_binaries/my-binary"]
```

The script `/tmp/my_binaries/my-binary` must be executable. If not the following error will be displayed:

```
open executable: Permission denied: OCI permission denied
```

Here's the full output:

```
$ podman-compose up
using podman version: podman version 3.4.1
podman pod create --name=tests --share net
8739e69897f2b7c7d004c7ea83df3b3a5fd22db6533720bfd6bffcd0040d651e
0
podman create --name=tests_test-container_1 --pod=tests --label io.podman.compose.config-hash=123 --label io.podman.compose.project=tests --label io.podman.compose.version=0.0.1 --label com.docker.compose.container-number=1 --label com.docker.compose.service=test-container -e PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/tmp/my_binaries" -v /tmp/my_binaries:/tmp/my_binaries:Z --add-host test-container:127.0.0.1 --add-host tests_test-container_1:127.0.0.1 python:3.9-slim /tmp/my_binaries/my-binary
6560b3335990700d0cec69a103404cadab52bbfd436e90347032bb6716265e94
0
podman start -a tests_test-container_1
Hello World
0
```